# How to combine multiple Windows Service PowerShell commands into a single statement?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, windows-services

I need to stop and then remove a Windows Service and the following PowerShell commands work successfully:

```
Get-Service "$ServiceName" | Stop-Service 
Get-Service "$ServiceName" | Remove-Service
```

I *think* it's possible to combine this into a single line of code, but in my PowerShell research the multiple piping to pass commandlet values to the next operation, or the use of a semicolon didn't work:

```
Get-Service "$ServiceName" | Stop-Service | Remove-Service  # Does not work
Get-Service "$ServiceName" | Stop-Service; Remove-Service # Does not work
```

Is there a way to combine these statements into a single line, or at least use the value of `Get-Service` to perform those operations without having to call it 2x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stop-Service` is one of those cmdlets that consumes the object. So, you'd have to supply it the `-PassThru` switch to allow the object to continue down the pipeline:

```
Get-Service "$ServiceName" | 
    Stop-Service -PassThru | 
    Remove-Service
```

As for your last example, the *semicolon* (`;`) is a means of *statement termination* in PowerShell, so you're essentially executing 2 commands where `Remove-Service` doesn't have anything to reference.

Comment: Awesome seems to work great - quick question is it `-PassTru` as your code shows or `-PassThru` like the description? Ironically the `-PassTru` works and `-PassThru` had issues. I looked for docs, but just found threads. Is it an alias, or what's the correct usage please?

Comment: @atconway, my mistake. I wrote this all on my phone with no autocorrect for syntax. The correct spelling is `-PassThru` and as far as I know, there's no such thing as just `-PassTru`

Comment: So I'm getting the following error using the proper `-PassThru` as recommended: _The following exception occurred while retrieving the string: ""Exception calling ""ToString"" with ""0"" argument(s): ""There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread._ I've tried removing any issues by placing on a single line (as opposed to multi-line command), but it's having an issue with the `-PassThru | Remove-Service` because if removed the `Stop-Service` works. `Get-Service "$ServiceName" | Stop-Service && Remove-Service` works but I understand this is a bit different.

Comment: @atconway, is there more you're not showing us? Also, I don't see how your last example would work as `Remove-Service`  would still need an argument. The working example should just be `Get-Service $ServiceName | Stop-Service -PassThru | Remove-Service`. Do you mind posting a picture of that one line with the error?

Comment: Yes my apologies I forgot to tag that this was PowerShell being issued from a C# application and I found that error was downstream when calling `New-Service` and unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach, with Powershell 7 you can execute multiple commands on one line with the `&&` operator like in classic cmd.

```
Stop-Service $Service && Remove-Service $Service
```

Comment: This did work well on PowerShell 7 and per the docs ensures that the 1st command succeeds prior to running the 2nd command.